# Deleting Cells in a notebook that is not the evaluation notebook

Tags: notebooks, cells

I use nb = CreateNotebook[] to create notebooks for processing messages.  How do I delete anything that had been written previously when I start a new processing run?

Comment: `NotebookClose`? `NotebookDelete[cellInOtherNB]`?

Comment: NotebookDelete[Cells[nb]] worked.  Thanks